# Yarn - remove package best practices

Tags: yarnpkg

If you want to remove a package using Yarn should you:

1. run `yarn remove [package]`

or

2. delete it from `package.json` and run `yarn install`

Do both work the same? Will #2 update `yarn.lock`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you run `yarn remove [package]` it will remove the package from node_modules and also from the yarn.lock file.

If you manually delete from package.json and then run `yarn install`, the deleted package is not installed and the yarn.lock file is not updated.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  My lock file updates when I manually remove a dependency and then run 'yarn'.

Comment: is correct, yarn.lock is not updated when you manually remove a dependency from package.json and run `yarn`.  However, if you subsequently update another dependency in package.json (change a semver symbol or something), then your manually removed dependency will be detected on the next yarn install and it appears the lock file will be updated accordingly.  I am running yarn 0.17.9

Comment: It means that `yack.lock` could be out of sync when someone by mistake remove a package from `package.json` and run `yarn install`. The question is how to fix `yarn.lock` in this case?

Comment: @luacassus, You can run `yarn add some-unlikely-random-package && yarn remove some-unlikely-random-package`, and that removes all stale entries.

Comment: "and run yarn install none of the package is install . yarn.lock files did not updated" -- this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It also removed it from package.json for me

Answer (score 18):

When you remove with **Yarn** by running the first approach (**#1**).

`yarn remove [package]`

Both your entries from `lockfile` and `package.json` are removed. Look out for this message in the terminal.

```
$ yarn remove x2js
yarn remove v0.27.5
[1/2] Removing module x2js...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
success Uninstalled packages.
Done in 2.34s.
```

The new file won't have the package.

If you follow the second (**#2**) approach and delete it from `package.json` and run:

`yarn install`

There will we no effect on your `lockfile`.

So it is better to remove packages using the first approach (**#1**).

If you have deleted some package(s) directly from `package.json` and don't know what was there then your `lockfile` is not up to date.

I would suggest you delete the `yarn.lock` file . and then run `yarn install`. This way, you will get an updated `yarn.lock` file.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to remove any package is

```
yarn remove "your package name"
```

Your package name should be same as your `package.json` file

Answer (score 1):

**Automatic Deletion**

`yarn remove <package-name>`

**Manual Deletion**

In case of manual removal of package from package.json ,

delete `yarn.lock` file and run `yarn install`